# How to refresh picasa album after deleting a photo from a album

Tags: asp.net, picasa

How to refresh picasa album after deleting a photo from a album...

i use following code to query photos of an album:
 Try

```
        Dim websvc As New PicasaService("abc")
        Dim query As New PhotoQuery(PicasaQuery.CreatePicasaUri(loginID, albumid))
        Dim oList As New List(Of AlbumPhotos)
        Dim feed As PicasaFeed = websvc.Query(query)

        For Each entry As PicasaEntry In feed.Entries
            Dim ac As New PhotoAccessor(entry)
            Dim oData As New AlbumPhotos
            With oData
                .FeedUri = entry.Media.Content.Attributes("url").ToString
                .ThumbnailUrl = entry.Media.Thumbnails(0).Attributes("url").ToString
                .Title = entry.Title.Text
                .Summary = entry.Summary.Text
                .PhotoID = ac.Id.ToString
            End With
            oList.Add(oData)
        Next

        feed = Nothing
        websvc = Nothing
        Return oList
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    Finally

    End Try
```

after deleting photo it returns same count of photo as previous and return the deleted picture....WHY???